# WiFi is unstable since a few months on my XPS 9560

Tags: wireless, atheros, 19.10, xps

since, if I remember correctly, late September my WiFi connection breaks off usually every few minutes, even though sometimes it takes a few hours for it to break. I am able to reliably break it in a timespan of seconds by repedeately switching the website I am accessing before the new one has been loaded. Streaming Videos reliably triggers the problem too after about 10 to 20 minutes.

The problem has existed before I upgraded from Ubutu 19.04 to Ubuntu 19.10 and still persists. I tried using wicd instead of Gnomes network manager, but the problem stayed. Other things I tried were turning pcie_aspm off and setting wifi.powersave = 2. The latter two are still present.

The internet connection can be reestablished by turning the wifi off and on again. Whenever the connection is lost I am no longer able to ping the router. A script I wrote that toggles

```
nmcli radio wifi off
nmcli radio wifi on
```

whenever I supposedly have a connection but cannot ping the router reestablishes the internet connection, but has many drawbacks so I don't want it as a permanent solution.

The wireless info script gives the following result: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jKF52B2sXt/

Even though `dmesg` sometimes shows error messages these messages don't mean that the internet connection broke and the absence of errors does not mean that the internet connection is working.

I am thankful for all potential solutions to this issue as well as tips on how to further debug this issue.

Comment: Can you disable TKIP encryption on the wifi router?

Comment: @Jeremy31 after some digging I switched WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK to WPA2-PSK. I hope that this is equivalent to disabling TKIP. Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you give the 2.4GHz a different name?

Comment: @Jereremy31 I did give the 2.4GHz one a different name, but the problem still occured. It does not seem to occur anymore after I now connect to the 2.4 GHz one under its different name. I will see if the connection continues to be stable. Thank you.